# Lowercase character in ksql stream column name make the column null

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-platform, ksqldb

I've created a new stream `post` from existing stream `post_raw` using:

`create stream "post" AS select id AS "ID", id AS "id" FROM post_review`.

When I run `SELECT id, "id" FROM post`, I am getting:

```
5ce0a41de36bcb6769fea850 | null
5ce0e44b9f3990676209a901 | null
5ce0e9613ec64f1132918f2a | null
5ce13c599f3990676209a915 | null
5ce1bf9c3ec64f1132918fb9 | null
```

It seams ksql makes the column value `null` if there is any lowercase character in column name.
Underlying topic for `post` is getting the data.

`print post` returns:

```
{"ROWTIME":1564559632738,"ROWKEY":"5ce0a41de36bcb6769fea850","ID":"5ce0a41de36bcb6769fea850","id":"5ce0a41de36bcb6769fea850"}
{"ROWTIME":1564559634853,"ROWKEY":"5ce0e44b9f3990676209a901","ID":"5ce0e44b9f3990676209a901","id":"5ce0e44b9f3990676209a901"}
{"ROWTIME":1564559636963,"ROWKEY":"5ce0e9613ec64f1132918f2a","ID":"5ce0e9613ec64f1132918f2a","id":"5ce0e9613ec64f1132918f2a"}
{"ROWTIME":1564559643305,"ROWKEY":"5ce13c599f3990676209a915","ID":"5ce13c599f3990676209a915","id":"5ce13c599f3990676209a915"}
{"ROWTIME":1564559643305,"ROWKEY":"5ce1bf9c3ec64f1132918fb9","ID":"5ce1bf9c3ec64f1132918fb9","id":"5ce1bf9c3ec64f1132918fb9"}
```

Why ksql making lowercase column value as null?

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing to do with lowercase/uppercase, but your issue is about double-quotes.

In the messages contained in your `post` topic, you have 4 attributes: `ROWTIME`, `ROWKEY`, `ID` and `id`. You do not have any attribute named `"id"` (with the double quotes in the label!)

Your query would return values if your content would have been formatted like this:

```
{"ROWTIME":..., "ROWKEY":..., "id":"5ce0a41de36bcb6769fea850", "\"id\"":"5ce0a41de36bcb6769fea850"}
```

I am pretty sure `SELECT id, ID FROM post` will return what you expect.

Or you can try to add the double-quotes in the the `AS` of your KSQL `create stream` command.